# How to use boost::asio to abstract file descriptors?

Tags: c++, linux, boost, boost-asio

Is there a tutorial on how to use the Boost::asio abstractions to multiple Linux file descriptors?

I'm basically looking for better abstractions to select on multiple file descriptors on a separate thread, with timeouts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not a tutorial but a working example:

http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.boost.asio.user/2699 or
http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2008/10/143892.php

They basically use [boost::asio::posix::stream_descriptor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/posix__stream_descriptor.html) to use native file descriptors with ASIO.

In the boost documentation there is also an example: [POSIX-specific chat client demonstrates how to use the posix::stream_descriptor class to perform console input and output](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/chat/posix_chat_client.cpp)

And perhaps you want to use a [reactor style](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/reactor.html) io_service.

Comment: The first of your links does not have a sample to download anymore.